# graphql-typegraphql modified example not working

Tags: node.js, graphql, prisma

I wanted to change the example code in src/index.ts to use apollo/server/express4 in https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/graphql-typegraphql , but it throws me the error: TypeError: graphqlError.toJSON is not a function. Because of this, nothing is working.

Here is my src/index.ts modified code:

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import * as tq from 'type-graphql'
import { PostCreateInput, PostResolver, SortOrder } from './PostResolver'
import { UserResolver } from './UserResolver'
//import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server'
//import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
//import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';

import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer'
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { DateTimeResolver } from 'graphql-scalars'
import { context } from './context'
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql'
import cors from 'cors'

const app2 = async () => {
  tq.registerEnumType(SortOrder, {
    name: 'SortOrder',
  });
  
  const schema = await tq.buildSchema({
    resolvers: [PostResolver, UserResolver, PostCreateInput],
    scalarsMap: [{ type: GraphQLScalarType, scalar: DateTimeResolver }],
  });
const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

// Set up Apollo Server
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
});

await server.start();

app.use(
  '/',
  cors<cors.CorsRequest>(),
  bodyParser.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server),
);

await new Promise<void>((resolve) => httpServer.listen({ port: 9000 }, resolve));
console.log(` Server ready at http://10.0.0.212:9000`)
}

app2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not passing the context in this snippet to the apollo server. You will need to pass it in the middleware function:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import * as tq from "type-graphql";
import { PostCreateInput, PostResolver, SortOrder } from "./PostResolver";
import { UserResolver } from "./UserResolver";
//import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server'
//import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
//import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';

import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { expressMiddleware } from "@apollo/server/express4";
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from "@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer";
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { DateTimeResolver } from "graphql-scalars";
import { context, Context } from "./context";
import { GraphQLScalarType } from "graphql";
import cors from "cors";

const app2 = async () => {
  tq.registerEnumType(SortOrder, {
    name: "SortOrder",
  });

  const schema = await tq.buildSchema({
    resolvers: [PostResolver, UserResolver, PostCreateInput],
    scalarsMap: [{ type: GraphQLScalarType, scalar: DateTimeResolver }],
  });
  const app = express();
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

  // Set up Apollo Server
  const server = new ApolloServer<Context>({
    schema,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
  });

  await server.start();

  app.use(
    "/",
    cors<cors.CorsRequest>(),
    bodyParser.json(),
    expressMiddleware(server, { context: async () => { return context } })
  );

  await new Promise<void>((resolve) =>
    httpServer.listen({ port: 9000 }, resolve)
  );
  console.log(` Server ready at http://10.0.0.212:9000`);
};

app2();
```

Also, currently it looks like `@apollo/server` is only compatible with `next` version of type-graphql since that version supports `graphql@16`. I am using the following deps and the example works for me:

```json
{
  "name": "typegraphql-example",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --no-notify --respawn --transpile-only src/index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.1.0",
    "@prisma/client": "4.5.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "graphql": "16",
    "graphql-scalars": "1.20.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "next"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/ws": "8.5.3",
    "prisma": "4.5.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "2.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
  }
}
```